# Scala: overflow despite use of Long when adding

Tags: scala

On 2.7.5.final, I'm attempting to add a Iterable list of Ints like so

```
def sum(xs: Iterable[Int]): Long = {
  var sum = 0L
  xs.foreach((x) => sum = sum + x)
  sum
}

println(sum(List(1, Integer.MAX_VALUE - 1)))
println(sum(Integer.MAX_VALUE - 1 to Integer.MAX_VALUE))
println(0L + Integer.MAX_VALUE - 1 + Integer.MAX_VALUE)
```

When I run, I get

```
2147483647
0
4294967293
```

And, you might say "use reduceLeft(_ + _)", but it seems to only be able to return the same type as elements in the list... but I want to accumulate to a Long, so I don't have overflow issues.

**Update 2009-10-28**

This is a bug in Range, as pointed out by Eastsun. It's been reported to the Scala team in [ticket 2535](http://lampsvn.epfl.ch/trac/scala/ticket/2535)

Comment: Hmm, println(sum(List(Integer.MAX_VALUE - 1, Integer.MAX_VALUE))) yields 4294967293.  This has something to do with the 'to' method I suspect.  Interesting question!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It's a bug of Range.
There is the source code of Range's foreach method:

```
override def foreach(f: Int => Unit) {
if (step > 0) {
  var i = this.start
  *val until = if (inInterval(end)) end + 1 else end*      //bug here!!!

  while (i < until) {
    f(i)
    i += step
  }
} else {
  var i = this.start
  val until = if (inInterval(end)) end - 1 else end

  while (i > until) {
    f(i)
    i += step
  }
}
```

}

Comment: It seems this bug exist in Scala2.7.x and current Scala 2.8.x.

Comment: Has anyone raised this bug in the Scala Trac?

Answer (score 6):

[Eastsun](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1635094/scala-overflow-despite-use-of-long-when-adding/1635198#1635198)'s answer gave a very good reason why you calculation overflows. As a workaround I would redefine the `sum` function to use `foldLeft`, which allows you to specify the accumulator.

```
def sum(xs: Iterable[Int]): Long =
  xs.foldLeft(0L)(_ + _)
```

or using the shorthand for `foldLeft` (which I quite like as it puts the starting value of the fold in front of the `Iterable` you are trying to fold).

```
def sum(xs: Iterable[Int]): Long =
  (0L /: xs)(_ + _)
```

In both cases, the code you were trying to run gives the correct results.

-- Flaviu Cipcigan